# How to enable cross-domain request on the server?

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, cross-domain

I have a json file hosted on my server. When I try to make an Ajax "GET" request to the json file, it fails.

See the console in Safari, it says "Failed to load resource".

Firebug shows "200 OK", but the response doesn't show up. Even Firebug does not show the JSON tab.

I believe this is because Cross Domain Requests are not allowed using AJAX.

I would like to know how can I overcome this? Also, if I want to enable cross-domain requests on my server, I believe a `crossdomain.xml` file or something needs to be created. I am not sure, but this is what I know. I searched on Google, but could not find any relevant links.

Any help in this is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I am not using any server-side scripting language (PHP, ASP.NET, etc). I am using Plain HTML and JavaScript / jQuery.

**UPDATE-2:**

I used the following code to make cross-domain requests:

```
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: '',
      jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
      url: 'http://myhosting.net/myjsonfile.json',
      success: function (jsonData) {
        alert("success")
        alert(jsonData);
      },
      error: function(errorObj) {
        alert(errorObj.statusText);

      },
    });
});
```

When i see in Firebug's "Net" tab, I see a JSON tab, and I am able to see the json response. However, the "success" callback handler doesn't get called, but the "error" callback handler gets invoked and I get the alert saying `parseerror`.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX cross domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain-you-are-connecting-from.com
```

on target server

in php:

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain-you-are-connecting-from.com");
```

in case you don't want to use server-scripting language: put this in (linux) console

```
a2enmod headers
```

and to your .htaccess file add ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain-you-are-connecting-from.com
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am not using any server side scripting language... rather using just plain HTML and JavaScript / jQuery... Can you modify your answer to meet this...?

Comment: HTML does not allow to change sent Headers

Comment: any idea as to whether I can do some setting on my server or ask the hosting provider to allow such requests?

Comment: I'll test it and update you the results.. thanks for your time!

Comment: Actually I am requesting the json file from a web-app. So in this case, how can I set the value for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.. Any idea?

Comment: Hi genesis: I updated my question. I tried JSONP to make cross-domain requests. Can you please check "Update-2" and tell me if you can help in this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mahi: can you show me your json response? It would be better to accept my answer here and create new question for this purpose

Comment: if we want to add this header into an HTML then what should we do for it to solve cross domain error?

Comment: I Tried it but still getting "Blocked loading mixed active content ..." :(

Comment: add your port number if you use a specific port

Comment: how can I limit  remote access to one single file but from any site?

Answer (score 6):

Put this in your **.htaccess** and plain ajax works

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

the solution given by genesis worked for me, however I had to omit the trailing slash on the url. ie:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain-you-are-connecting-from.com");
```

Comment: where should I add this header line in my client side code?