# Windows 8 HTML 5 Web APP AJAX post not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, windows-phone-8

I am creating Windows Phone 8 HTML 5 App. I trying to ajax post for getting weather information. But i am not getting any response. I am unable to trace the problem behind it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var apiUrl = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=London&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=KEY GOES HERE";

        //CALL BACK FUNCTION

        function mapWeather() {
            $("#contentPanel").text("111");
            $.ajax({
                url: apiUrl,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#contentPanel").text("adfdf");
                }
            });
        }
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="row-fluid">
        <div class="input-append">
            <input type="text" id="searchCity" />
            <button type="button" id="addCity" unselectable="on" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="mapWeather()">+</button>
        </div>
<div id="contentPanel">
        testing
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason :

```
is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

You are trying to do AJAX cross-domain.

**EDIT**

Example of a, here in php, proxy.php :

```
<?
$url=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$from=strpos($url, 'url=')+4;
$url=substr($url, $from);
echo utf8_decode(file_get_contents($url));
?>
```

Then you call the ajax as

```
var apiUrl = "proxy.php?url=http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=London&format=json&num_of_days=YOURKEY";
```

Comment: You need to make a proxy, serverside

Comment: can u pls give me an example ?

Comment: +1 for tracing the error, oh do i need to add server side coding. i just thinking of deploying application in phone itself. I just dont lik 2 go for a server side. Is there any other way ?

Comment: If you have control over the server, you could try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6871067/1407478, OR see this, http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/phonegap.html, allowCrossDomainPages, though I have never tried it.

Comment: hi thanks, i already heard about phonegap. let me try on that. so anyway for my question the issue relates to cross domain and so i accept your answer. Thanks...

Comment: Thank you! Remember to remove your key from the URL (apiURL)!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason I mentioned `callback=?` in my comment above is because **weatheronline.com** supports JSONP which *does* support cross-domain requests.

This works for me from PC browser. I don't have a Windows 8 phone, so I can't test:

```
var apiUrl = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=London&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=KEY HERE&callback=?";

$("#addCity").click(function () {
   mapWeather(); 
});

//CALL BACK FUNCTION
function mapWeather() {
    $("#contentPanel").text("111");
    $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#contentPanel").text(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using JQuery 2.x? This supports Windows 8 apps. See here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-windows-store-applications-with-jquery-2-0/

Comment: @yes am using `jquery-2.0.0.min.js`

Comment: its given there in link as `No More Same-Origin Issues` but am getting that issue

Comment: Maybe try and reach out to the JQuery folks to help - let them know it works in Chrome, but not in the Windows 8 app: http://bugs.jquery.com/newticket