# Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead with JSON REST

Tags: ajax, json, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I am having trouble implementing the Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead feature with a JSON web Service.

I have looked at all the examples on this website and can't find anything that will work. I know my JSON web service works; I can enter the address in my browser and it returns the JSON I expect with the MIME type set to "application/json".

I have this JavaScript in the

```
<body>
```

of my HTML page:

```
<script>
    $('#typeahead').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            return $.getJSON(
                'http://localhost:8732/IngredientsService/search/',
                { query: query },
                function (data) {
                    return process(data);
                });
        }
    });
</script>
```

I have this code as my "input":

```
<input type='text' id='typeahead' class='typeahead' data-provide="typeahead" data-items="10" />
```

Can anyone explain why this is not working?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Are you getting any error in the console? Do you see any activity in the network?

Comment: Is that your JSON format is valid?

Comment: You can validate your json on http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Sorry, my description wasn't very helpful. The error is: nothing happens. I don't see any error messages in the console (Firebug). How do I check to see if there is any activity on the network?

Comment: what does it say, of you add `console.log(data)` as the very first line in `function(data)` ?

Comment: Added the line. Nothing was written to the console.

Comment: I used Chrome to and viewed the 'Network' tab on the Developer tools... and it appears that the Web Service is not being accessed. The URI works, so I'm not sure why this would be the case.

Comment: Is the domain of the application same as the domain of the service? You should get some error in the chrome console.

Comment: Is your Console is enabled?

Comment: They are on the same network. There is no error in the console. I feel like the Service is not being accessed.

My console (in Chrome) is enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the last comment ("*web service not being accessed*") - have you tried the more normal / documented approach?

```
$('#typeahead').typeahead({
  source: function (query, process) {
     return $.get('http://localhost:8732/IngredientsService/search/', { query: query }, function (data) {
       return process(data.options); //if JSON is [ "options" : { ...} 
     });
  }
});
```

$.getJSON is not nessecary, but useful when you want to load an entire JSON and inject potion of it as a source for the typeahead

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8732/IngredientsService/search/", function(json) {
  $("#typeahead").typeahead({
    source : json.options //again, dont know the structure of the JSON
  });
});
```

Comment: No this hasn't worked. Does the Service URL expect a parameter? I.e. should I be mapping my Service method to a value form the URL?

Comment: I guess your index / calling script is not http://localhost:8732/ ?? It may be the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) Same Origin Policy that is your problem.

Comment: Is there a way of resolving issue?

Comment: Yes, use a [proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16495740/1407478) or try [JSONP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2686406/1407478)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see from the typeahead documentation, the source key in the parameters object is not valid.

It should look more like this I think:

```
 $('#typeahead').typeahead({
     remote: 'http://localhost:8732/IngredientsService/search/q=%QUERY' 
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qVjsu/

Comment: Source is an option used. I tried to use the above but with no luck. :(

Answer (score 0):

It's better to omit return when using async sources because process() will be triggered twice

```
$('#typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        $.getJSON('/search/json/'+ query), function (data) {
            return process(data);
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    items: 8
});
```