# No Ajax response even though URL is correct?

Tags: ajax, jquery

i get error in firebug when i try to get the data from the second url, but when i try the url in comments (the first one) everything is ok,

```
function build()
{ 
   $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
         contentType: "application/json",
         crossDomain: true,
         /// url: "http://localhost:9100/todo-0.1/data.json",
         url:'localhost:9000/rest/admin/component?componentUri=file:/home/workspace/app/5-Integration/',
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data) 
                {
                 var n=data.links.link[1]['@href'].indexOf("file");
                 var ContObject=new Object();
                     ContObject.data=new Object();
                     ContObject.data["title"]= decodeURI(data.links.link[1]          ['@href'].substring(n));
                     ContObject.state="open";

                     ContObject.metadata=new Object();
                     ContObject.metadata["id"]= decodeURI(data.links.link[1]['@href'].substring(n));   
                 var jsonText = JSON.stringify(ContObject);
                 var output="<div>";
                     output+=  jsonText;
                     output+="</div>";
                     document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
                   alert("success");

                },
          error: function (data,status) 
               {
                  console.log("ERROR");
                  console.log(status);
               }    
         });
```

thanks for guidance

Comment: *i get error in firebug* - OK.  What is the error you get in firebug?

Comment: i get error in console, and Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error"}

Comment: what do you get as output by `success: function (data) { console.log(data); }`

Comment: i get nothing, if i use this url, and i don't know why

Comment: i tried http:// localhost:9000/rest/admin/co... also but doesn't work

Comment: if you get nothing, then the error is inside `localhost:9000/rest/admin/component?componentUri=file:/home/workspace/app/5-Integration/`document. when you access this by browser, you get nothing too?
Does the server on port 9000 allow cross domain requests?

Comment: yes,when i access by the brower i get my data. Can you explain what do you mean by the server allows cross domain requests.thank you

Comment: i add a new parameter in error: function (data,status,errorThrown){  console.log(errorThrown);} and i get this error [Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:9100/todo-0.1/jquery-1.7.2.min.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 4" data: no] { name="NS_ERROR_FAILURE", message="Failure", result=2147500037, more...}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871021/how-to-enable-cross-domain-request-on-the-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`url:'localhost:9000/rest/admin/co....`

must be

`url:'http://localhost:9000/rest/admin/co....`

**update:**

enable cross domain requests: [How to enable cross-domain request on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871021/how-to-enable-cross-domain-request-on-the-server)

debug:

```
success: function (data) { console.log(data); }
```

Comment: i have used two servers. i run my application using  port :9000 and  so i want to get data from  http://localhost:9100. so i can't .

finally, i solved the problem, by using just one server 9100.

thank you all for help