# $.post (to different domain) not working (node.js / express app on port 8081)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I receive the error `POST https://thewebsite.com 400 (Bad Request)` when using $.post that way:

```
$.post("https://website.com/blabla",
{
  domain: "infoinfo.com",
  room: "someInfo",
  application: "someInfo",
  ident: "someInfo",
},
function (data,status) {
  alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

I tried setting `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");` in my route but that didn't work.

Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Ps.: The server I am posting to is service website (xirsys.com), I am pretty sure they allow external domains already. I'll contact them during the day if I can't find a solution (I am using the jQuery post as they suggested :/

Comment: CrossDomain must be enabled on the server you are posting data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link I was posting to was actually not good. The service I am using updated the link in their API to reflect the right one.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the Same-origin policy. All the browsers as a security measure would not allow any cross domain requests.

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy
```

Like in your case you are posting to thewebsite.com domain from a different domain. A work around is to use the jsonp (the server should support json padding) from the jquery.

Check these sites for more info

```
http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871021/how-to-enable-cross-domain-request-on-the-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your AJAX call:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json"
```

Another reason maybe because of the same origin policy:

> In computing, the same origin policy is an important security concept
>   for a number of browser-side programming languages, such as
>   JavaScript. The policy permits scripts running on pages originating
>   from the same site to access each other's methods and properties with
>   no specific restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and
>   properties across pages on different sites.

You can find out more informations about this issue from MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) or doing some research on Google about this topic.

---

You can try to use `$.axax()` like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "https://website.com/blabla",
    data: {
        domain: "infoinfo.com",
        room: "someInfo",
        application: "someInfo",
        ident: "someInfo"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (e) {
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    }

});
```

Comment: The post is actually to https://beta.xirsys.com/getIceServers -- I'm pretty sure they allow external domains already. How would you go about adding the contentType/dataType into my example?

Comment: Actually my thing didn't work, it only got the default json from the site. Trying yours.

Comment: @DanyP.. Accept the useful answer or post your solution and accept it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SAMPLE REQUEST:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://yoururl",
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: JSON.stringify(somejson),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
```

SAMPLE RESPONSE IN PYTHON:

```
response = HttpResponse(json.dumps('{"status" : "success"}'))
response.__setitem__("Content-type", "application/json")
response.__setitem__("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

return response
```