# Getting the Error on making ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have made an Ajax call to one of my pages sitting in the server. When I am making the Ajax call, I am not getting the data. But instead I am getting status 200 OK with red font-color in the firebug. I am not able to figure out what the problem is.

I am making an ajax call to these api pages:

```
  [{"ID":"001","name":"Naidu","school":"Hyd","hobby":"cricket"}]
```

My ajax call is like:

```
  $.ajax({ url: 'http://something.com/api/name',
       data:{},
     type: 'post',
      dataType: "json",
    success: function(output) {
     //alert("SUCCESS");
      alert(output);
    }});
```

Comment: I suggest against `alert()`, and instead suggest `console.log()`, you get something more meaningful.

Comment: Server Response code 200 OK just means no transaction errors were encountered. What does your code look like where it is being sent? Are you returning a value?

Comment: does the alert fire? Try echoing out the request on the server to make sure it's hitting the right place.

Comment: In the code above, what's inside your `data`?

Comment: if i type the url i am getting the response what i have shown in the first line

Comment: I added the console.log() but i am not getting anything ... but if i remove the dataType:json , then by default it should return me at least Html response. As the whole data is inside Body tag when i checked it with firebug tool

Answer (score 0):

Make sure API returns a status message when call is made.

Also retured output should be in json format. If you want to see exact output even if that is not json , remove DataType:"json" part from script and you should be able to see exact response.

Chances are that API isnt returning a message in one of the two cases or returned output is not json datatype.

Comment: See When i type the URL i am getting a blank page with the data i have mentioned in line 1. And also i checked that it's a valid Json Data.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not doing cross-domain ajax.

Comment: You cannot perform ajax request to another domain than the origin. To enable this you need to allow 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain-you-are-connecting-from.com/ on the target server.

Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871021/how-to-enable-cross-domain-request-on-the-server