# Cross domain issues, HTTP requests with different ports

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-headers

I made a client-side web application for fun and I recently try to integrate it with server-side stuff.

Using brunch as a starter for client and gulp as a start for server.

I am not sure how to send requests from client when they have different ports. I get a cross domain request issues. I googled but still have no clue.

Comment: Did you stackoverflowed? like [How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different ports are treated as different domains, so XHR cross-domain rules apply. You could set server-side to pass XHR requests using proper headers:
[How to enable cross-domain request on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871021/how-to-enable-cross-domain-request-on-the-server)

Another way is to prepare some cross-domain proxy that could forward your requests wuthout editing your server code, e.g.:

- https://github.com/gr2m/CORS-Proxy
- https://github.com/premist/node-crossdomain-proxy