# Not able to log in & getting the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined"

Tags: php, mysql, rest, ionic-framework

I am trying to login through my ionic app using php mysql as backend and using RESTful web service... After running my project I am getting this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined" at services.js
Whats wrong with my code?

My Controller is:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $state, LoginService) {
 $scope.login = function () {
    var obj={};
    obj.username=$scope.uname;
    obj.password=$scope.pswd;
    LoginService.loginUser(obj)
    .then(function (data) {
        $state.go("tab.dash");          //log in successfull
    }, function (data) {
        //log in failed
    });
 }
};
```

My Service is:

```
.service('LoginService', function ($q, $http) {
 return {
    loginUser: function (loginData) {
        var deferred = $q.defer(),
            promise = deferred.promise;

        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost/login.php',
            method: "POST",
            data: loginData,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.data.error.code === "000") {
                    console.log("User login successful: " + JSON.stringify(response.data));
                    deferred.resolve(response.data);
                } else {
                    console.log("User login failed: " + JSON.stringify(response.data.error));
                    deferred.reject(response.data);
                }
            }, function (error) {
                console.log("Server error on Login " + JSON.stringify(error));
                deferred.reject(error);
            });

        promise.success = function (fn) {
            promise.then(fn);
            return promise;
        };
        promise.error = function (fn) {
            promise.then(null, fn);
            return promise;
        };
        return promise;
    }
  };
 });
```

My HTML code is:

```
<ion-view view-title="Login">
<ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
  <div class="list list-inset">
<ion-list> 

    <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
        <span class="input-label">Username</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="uname">
    </label>

    <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
        <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="pswd">
    </label>

 </ion-list>

</div>   
  <br>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <button class="button ion-log-in button-block button-calm animated fadeInRight" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
</div>
```

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, x-xsrf-token");

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$loginData = json_decode($postdata);
$email = $loginData->email;
$password = $loginData->password;

$userData = array('userID' => '', 'userName' => '', 'email' => '');

$conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "") or die('{"userData":'.json_encode($userData).', "error": {"code": "003", "message": "Login error! Code: 003"}}');
mysqli_select_db($conn, "userDB") or die('{"userData":'.json_encode($userData).', "error": {"code": "004", "message": "Login error! Code: 004"}}');

if(!empty($email) && !empty($password)){

//echo($email.'  '.$password);

$email = mysqli_escape_string($email);
$password = mysqli_escape_string(md5($password));

$results = mysqli_query("SELECT id,username, email, password FROM users WHERE email='".$email."' AND password='".$password."' LIMIT 1") or die('{"error":"Login error! Code: 003"}'); 
$match  = mysqli_num_rows($results);

$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

if($match > 0 ){        
    if ($res['active'] = 1) {
        // login success
        $userData['id'] = $res['id'];
        $userData['username'] = $res['username'];
        $userData['email'] = $res['email'];
        echo ('{"userData":'.json_encode($userData).',"error":{"code":"000","message":"Logged in as '.$userData['userName'].' '.'."}}');
    } else {                
        echo('{"userData":'.json_encode($userData).', "error":{"code":"001","message":"Your account has not been ativated. Please verify your account by clicking on the link in the activation email sent when you registered.\r\n If you did not receive an email, click on the Resend Activation Email link and make sure the email is not being blocked by your spam filter."}}');
    }
}else{
    // login failed
    echo ('{"userData":'.json_encode($userData).', "error": {"code": "002","message": "The email or password you entered is incorrect."}}');            
}
} else {
// something failed with submitting data, should never get here!
echo('{"userData":'.json_encode($userData).', "error": {"code":"005", "message": "Login error! Code: 005"}}');


}
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried add port to XML request ( like http://localhost:8100/login.php )? and Can you provide result from http://localhost/login.php ?

Comment: I want to login in but I am not able to do so..

Comment: from `url: 'http://localhost/login.php' ` remove the http://localhost/ part

Comment: install plugin which i suggest you in answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871021/how-to-enable-cross-domain-request-on-the-server

Comment: removing localhost did not work..

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right you are doing an [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to a different domain than your page is on. So the browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. You need to do something different when you want to do a cross-domain request. A tutorial about how to achieve that is *[Using CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)*.

When you are using postman they are not restricted by this policy. Quoted from *[Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html)*:

> Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same origin policy. Extensions aren't so limited. An extension can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests cross-origin permissions.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/20035319#20035319)

---

**Quick Solution for localhost:** Install [this CORS plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) to chrome which allow you to request over cross domain.

Comment: So ? install CORS plugin..it allows you to communicate over cross domain