# Reverse Proxy: Accessing .Net Web Application from Java Web Application

Tags: java, .net, proxy, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

**So here is the scenario which we have/want to implement:**

1. We have a java spring based web application deployed on apache tomcat.
2. In our web application we will provide a 3rd party web application link which is .net based to user. On click of which user will be redirected to .net application but the domain and context root shown in the browser url will remain same that is of java application.
3. We cannot ask 3rd party team to change anything in their application.
4. Whatever we have to change should be in our code, also as far as we could we should refrain ourself from any apache tomcat level changes.

**Here are the things which we implemented so far:**

1. We tried to implement reverse proxy using following link: https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet
2. So the basic funda was to call the 3rd party url as a webservice and edit the httpresponse and add our domain and context path to the urls in any file received as response. Though this is not a good solution and consumes lot of time and space but it does the job.

**Issue Which we are facing:**

1. Everything is working fine except the ajax request in the .net application.
2. The Error thrown is: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.

**Here is the code fragment for doing httpresponse modification task:**

```
protected void copyResponseEntity(HttpResponse proxyResponse, HttpServletResponse servletResponse,
                                    HttpRequest proxyRequest, HttpServletRequest servletRequest)throws IOException {
  
    HttpEntity entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(proxyResponse.getEntity());
    if (entity.isChunked()) {
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            String proxyBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
              proxyBody = proxyBody.replaceAll("/.netContextRoot/", "/ourContextRoot/.netContextRoot/");
    
            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(proxyBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    
            OutputStream os = servletResponse.getOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10 * 1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = stream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
              os.write(buffer, 0, read);
              if (doHandleCompression || stream.available() == 0 /* next is.read will block */) {
                os.flush();
              }
            }
            // Entity closing/cleanup is done in the caller (#service)
          } else {
    
            String proxyBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            proxyBody = proxyBody.replaceAll("/.netContextRoot/", "/ourContextRoot/.netContextRoot/");
    
            EntityUtils.updateEntity(proxyResponse, new StringEntity(proxyBody));
            HttpEntity entity2  =  proxyResponse.getEntity();
    
            OutputStream servletOutputStream = servletResponse.getOutputStream();
    
            entity2.writeTo(servletOutputStream);
    
    }
}
```

Can anybody help us out with this scenario, Also if you have any other solution without making any changes in apache level then pls do mention.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: When you say `3rd party web application link`, is this just an API or has UI also? By the looks of the code, it seems like you want to communicate to the 3rd party API and show some data. Why can't you wrap another API on top of the 3rd party and expose that API to the user?

Comment: it is web based application that means 3rd party has an UI, and that UI needs to be showcased in browser, but the domain in browser url should be ours.

Comment: Can't you use iframe? It can be still be your App and allowed for 3rd party to display the application

Comment: We get a cross domain or cors exception while using iframe, as the .net application is having a different domain.

Comment: If you don't have control over asking the 3rd party domain to even allow your application to access it over IFrame or similar requirement, then you are only left with wrapping all the functionality and creating a wrapper on that UI. Any reverse proxy on that would eventually also start showing blockers with the security layer they introduce. Imagine, if we did a reverse proxy on any banking domain and listen in the middle for all the requests! (man-in-the-middle)

Comment: Yes Nagaraj, you right, but its the requirement which we want to achieve.
Do you have any working example of wrapper on the ui in java?

Comment: There are some examples, can you provide more details on your third party app? What is the Auth used? Do they provide API's or every user in your app has a login to that application also?

Comment: Single sign on auth is used, ie basic auth is there, so we have to pass some credentials in header of request while accessing it.

Comment: Oh, Basic Auth? There are plenty of Apps that require Basic Auth and triggering the [API](https://docs.agora.io/en/All/faq/restful_authentication#sample-code-1:~:text=Sample%20code,-The%20following%20sample%20codes%20implement%20token). Not sure if you have tried/seen those. So for every API you want, write a wrapper API method on your side.

Comment: I think @NagarajTantri had the best approach when recomending the iframe use; the CORS exceptions can be resolved by passing the ["allow cross domain"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871021/how-to-enable-cross-domain-request-on-the-server) either in your end or on apache (you said you should refrain from it, but not that it can't be done at all - would be a single setting there if it doesn't work on your end).

Comment: @SammuelMiranda I think he also mentioned that they can't change CORS headers in the 3rd party application. Considering those CORS has to be enabled for that service who should allow (3rd party), it would again become a problem.

Comment: If the only issue you are facing with code you included above is the c# exception with a particular type of requests from the client, then I would start debugging this by trying to find out how these failing requests are different from the working ones. I suspect that your code is messing up with some requests and causing the c# application to behave differently. You can use wireshark to analyze the requests and responses to see the difference.

Comment: @Mustafa: yes that error is occurring as i have to edit the httpresponse for adding our applications context path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found some answers to dodge PageRequestManagerParserErrorException.

1. [You can refer this link if you are allowed to make changes in 3rd party application](https://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it):Do read the comments for better understanding.
2. You can create a new application for only reverse proxy purpose having contextroot name same as the 3rd party's context root and deploy it in your applications domain, so you will not have to edit the body content of http response for setting up your application path. And then you can call this application from your older one as both will be in same domain.
3. I did dig up a little bit in the PageRequestManagerParserErrorException and some how found out a flow, The event validation of .net triggers PageRequestManagerParserErrorException when it comes to know that you have edited the httpresponse and the logic they have used is that they just check up the length of httpresponse with the actual length of httpresponse. So if you somehow manage to edit the httpresponse without changing the response's length then boom You have achieved the task.

Note:

a) [You can use this link to achieve reverse proxy](http://%20https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet): As this has only code level change, so its very simple to achieve and also there is no server level config changes required.

b) PageRequestManagerParserErrorException occurs when you edit httpResponse before sending it to client and its triggered by eventValidation of .net.

c) 1st solution is useless if you are not allowed to make any change in the 3rd party application just like mine scenario. For time being I went with the 3rd one as it did the job without much effort.